# How to find max values in each group in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

How could I generate a new summary data.frame with only the largest values of a data.frame

I tried the code below, but the result was not what I expected.

```
n<-c('A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C')
x1<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
x2<-c(9,8,7,4,5,6,1,2,3)

df<-data.frame(n, x1, x2)


df%>%
  group_by(n)%>%
  mutate('x1'=max('x1'), 'x2'=max('x2'))

i wanted this

n   X1  X2
A   7   9
B   8   8
C   9   7
```

Comment: Generally one will confuse dplyr functions by quoting column names. And I don't think `mutate` is the right dplyr verb for aggregation.

Comment: If you had consulted the help page for `mutate`, rather than posting a reply, you should have seen the link to `summarise` in the See Also section.

Answer (score 4):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(n ) %>% summarise(across(x1:x2, max))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  n        x1    x2
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         7     9
2 B         8     8
3 C         9     7
```

Comment: hello, this one resolves, but would it only serve for a number? and if I have a no-data (NA)

Comment: @carvalhosantos, if you have `NA` in your data then use: `summarise(across(x1:x2, max, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: i try in my real data.frame, but i have errror: `Erro: `across()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: @carvalhosantos, `summarise` is a dplyr verb, not sure why you are getting that error.

Answer (score 3):

Just change it to `x1 = max(x1)` without the quotes and change `mutate` into `summarise`.

```
df%>%
    group_by(n)%>%
    summarise(x1=max(x1), x2=max(x2))
```

Comment: I use quote when the R don't be recognized name

Comment: Yeah well that is not what you are supposed to do. See `?mutate` and `?summarise`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `across` with `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(n) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), max, na.rm = TRUE))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  n        x1    x2
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         7     9
2 B         8     8
3 C         9     7
```

---

Or use `aggregate` in `base R`

```
aggregate(.~ n, df, max)
```

Comment: this is fine, but if i need to select specific columns

Comment: @carvalhosantos just specify with any of the select-helpers `c(x1, x2)` or `starts_with('x')` etc

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Map(max, .SD), n]
```

gives

```
   n x1 x2
1: A  7  9
2: B  8  8
3: C  9  7
```